# Using jQuery to set/retrieve multiple key/value pairs in one cookie using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My goal here is to cut down the number of cookies I'm using to store things like persistent states into a single cookie by setting and retrieving multiple key/value pairs within a single cookie using an array.

I'm mostly interested in knowing if someone else has already done this and has written a plugin for it, as I would think this has been done before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize the object into a JSON string. That would make it super simple to re-load the object. See [question 191881](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery) for information on how to serialize an object to JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: This is the usual approach. Note you'll still need to encode the JSON string for use in a cookie (eg. using `encodeURIComponent`), because JSON may contain semicolons, Unicode and other charactes that won't fit into a cookie.

Comment: I'm going to write a plugin that automates this task and post it as the answer, but thank you for these responses.